# Python getting content out of files in located in different folders

Tags: python-3.x

Hy together, I have Problem with my code, because it dont do what it should. I will describe what I actualy want to do. I have Folder caled test with is the root folder with a few web page folders containing php files from wich I want to get some content and write it in a txt file. The codes run and dont give any errors but it also don't create the words.txt file with the content I wanted. Any Idea why?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import os
import re

rootdir ='.../test' # I write here the full path but due to privacy reassons only the folders name 

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".php"):
                with io.open(file, encoding="utf-8") as f, io.open('words.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as g:
                    for line in f:
                        h = re.sub(r"$slimname = '([^']+)'", r"\1", line.rstrip())
                        m = re.sub(r"'alwaysfound_text' => '([^']+)'", r"\1", line.rstrip())
                        l = re.sub(r"'alwaysfound_place' => '([^']+)'", r"\1", line.rstrip())
                        j = re.sub(r"'alwaysfound_job' => '([^']+)'", r"\1", line.rstrip())
                        k = re.sub(r"var_keyword_hidden_generic' => '([^']+)'", r"\1", line.rstrip())
                        print (h, m, l, j, k, file = g)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a few issues with the code:

- you open file for 'w' but probably want 'a' (append)
- indentation is minor mess, but shouldn't be a problem
- you open filename but disregard its subdirectory - use `with io.open(os.path.join(subdir, file), encoding="utf-8") as f`

Answer (score 1):

You probably rewrite the file word.txt for every next "`file in files`" as you open it with the mode "w" (which means "rewrite"). Try use mode "a" (which means "append").

Comment: But it still dont go gthrough the rest of the folders, it just enters the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a blank between print statement and the first brace.
This should result in a syntax error.
Remove it and test your code again.

Comment: No it shouldn't. The space before the bracket doesn't matter